# Blank cells in table are locked and I dont know why

Tags: business-objects, webi

Does anyone know why these cells have suddenly become un-clickable/locked?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s80r5.png)

Comment: Are you in  "Reading" instead of "Design" mode (upper right corner of WebI)?

Comment: No, im definitely in Design. I have just had the support team remote in. They can not figure it out either. Advised to re-build the report and see if it happens again :(

Comment: Have you tried the report in the Rich Desktop Client?

Comment: Which cells are you referencing? are there multiple tables and the "Gap" is the unclickable locked cells?  have you looked at the report in structure only mode vs w/ data?